# Who invented the "Histogram"?

Tags: distributions, terminology, histogram, history

While going through Wikipedia's article [History of statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_statistics)

I found

> **In 1786 William Playfair (1759-1823) introduced the idea of graphical representation into statistics. He invented the line chart, bar chart, and histogram and incorporated them into his works on economics, the Commercial and Political Atlas.**

William Playfair(22 September 1759 – 11 February 1823) invented the line chart, bar chart, and histogram.

And in the [Histogram article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram)

> **A histogram is an approximate representation of the distribution of numerical data. It was first introduced by Karl Pearson.**

From ine.es

> **academic and learned online publications, take this extract from an online entry for “Karl Pearson: “Two days later he [i.e., Pearson] introduced the histogram – a term he coined to designate a 'time-diagram' to be used for historical purposes”**

Histogram was first introduced and coined by Karl Pearson(27 March 1857 – 27 April 1936).

The context is not clear and I'm a bit confused on the invention of Histogram.

Does anyone know who first invented/introduced a Histogram?  I would be happy to receive any additional reference from you.

Comment: History of ideas is too complicated to be left to amateurs... and I am one too. Pearson's contribution was the term _histogram_, not the idea. I don't know that Playfair ever had a histogram modern sense, and others were there earlier than Playfair with bar charts. Guerry, A.-M. 1833. _Essai sur la Statistique Morale de la France._ Paris: Crochard.has also been suggested as if not the first, then an early user of histograms.

Comment: Parsing "histogram" as intended to mean time diagram or history diagram (which I have also seen) is utter nonsense. The root _histos_ here implies being upright, and also occurs differently in _histology_.  So, if as I have occasionally done, you present a histogram with horizontal bars, then it's on this etymology not a histogram, but I have not seen that objection.  Full non-disclosure. I use Wikipedia just about every day with gratitude and yet distrust it mightily on anything close to my home territory.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you for the comments.

Comment: Line charts go back before Playfair too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I know of at the moment is by an article by Rufilanchas in 2017 [1]: in it, he says that Pearson, the first person to use the word (not the first who used such a diagram), used it in relation to how he believed that the **vertical** alignment of columns to represent frequency distributions is preferable to it aligned horizontally:

"...Pearson, who seemed to be mostly interested in the psychological effect of the difference in orientation of the bars, found some “optical advantage of vertical over horizontal columns” (Pearson, 1938: 144), hence the choice for a word **specifically meaning a vertical structure** like a mast as the element for the root of the new word “histogram”..."

We see how this preference for the vertical arrangement of the columns relates to the prefix 'histo' in a little more detail in the Oxford English Dictionary which states its etymology: "... Etymology: < histo- (in histology n.), ultimately < ancient Greek ἱστός mast, (upright) beam of a loom [3], (woven) web < ἵστασθαι , medio-passive of ἱστάναι to (cause to) stand (see stand v.)..."

References and notes:
[1] Rufilanchas, D.R. On the origin of Karl Pearson’s term 'histogram'. Revista Estadistica Española. 2017:192. pg 29-35 (you can get articles and issues at https://www.ine.es/ss/Satellite?c=Page&cid=1254735226759&pagename=ProductosYServicios%2FPYSLayout&L=0).
[2] "histo-, comb. form." OED Online. Oxford University Press, September 2021. Web. 1 October 2021.
[3] Though not part of this question, here it leads to how the prefix 'histo' relates to the medical term histology: tissues appear like the woven cloth made using the vertical loom, both of which use the word 'histo'; see Mossakowska-Gaubert, M. A new kind of loom in early Roman Egypt? How iconography could explain (or not) papyrological evidence" (2020). in Mossakowska-Gaubert, M. Egyptian textiles and their production: ‘word’ and ‘object’. Zea books. pg 13-21, and https://chs.harvard.edu/susan-t-edmunds-picturing-homeric-weaving/#n.22.